# Swift - HMAC SHA512 - Invalid Signature

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, alamofire, hmac

im trying to work with the Bittrex API (found [here](https://bittrex.com/home/api))

However i always get the response:

```
SUCCESS: {
    message = "INVALID_SIGNATURE";
    result = "<null>";
    success = 0;
}
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
//NONCE
let timeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
let nonceTime = String(Int(floor(timeInterval)))
//STANDARDS
let paras:Parameters = ["apikey": key, "nonce": nonceTime]
let uri = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalances?apikey=\(key)&nonce=\(nonceTime)"
//SIGN
let secretKey = HMAC(algorithm: .sha512, key: uri).update(string: secret)!.final()
let skey = String("\(secretKey)")
//HEADER
let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["apisign": "\(skey)"]
let getMethod:HTTPMethod = .get

Alamofire.request(uri, method: getMethod, parameters: paras, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
    print("\(response)")
}
```

Does someone know what i am doing wrong?
For the HMAC i am using [IDZSwiftCommonCrypto](https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto)

Comment: Are you sure this is due to HMAC ?

Comment: Yes, the signature has to do with adding a signed message.